# How to work date slider in shiny line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a shiny app where the user can choose a range of dates, a wilderness, a species, a life stage, and finally a site id. What should appear is a line plot with bd_load for each time point. However, my script for some reason will only show one data point for the year 2016 no matter what range of dates I choose.

Data

```
bd_data <- bd_data <- structure(list(id = c(10008, 10008,10008), date = c(2018,2019,2020), species = c("ramu", "ramu", "ramu"),
                          wilderness = c("yosemite", "yosemite", "yosemite"), visual_life_stage = c("adult", "adult", "adult"),
                          bd = c(1,2,3)))
```

```
UI

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  
  
  #includeCSS(here("NPS_ShinyApp/theme.css")),
  
  theme = theme,
  
  
  titlePanel(""),
  
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(8,
                    h1(strong("National Park Service App - RIBBiTR ")))),
  
  
  navbarPage("", inverse = T,
             
             tabPanel("Home", icon = icon("info-circle"),
                      fluidPage(
                        fluidRow(
                          h1(strong("Disclaimer"), style = "font-size:20px;"),
                          
                          column(12, p(""))),
                        
                        fluidRow(
                          h1(strong("Intended Use"),style = "font-size:20px;"),
                          
                          column(12, p(""))),
                        
                        fluidRow(
                          h1(strong("Data Collection"),style = "font-size:20px;"),
                          column(12, p(""))))),
             
             
             tabPanel(title = "Site Map", icon = icon("globe-asia"),
                      
                      sidebarLayout(
                        
                        sidebarPanel(
                          
                                                          sliderInput(inputId = "bd_date",
                                            label = "Select an annual range",
                                            min = min(bd_data$date), max = max(bd_data$date), 
                                            value =  c((max(bd_data$date) - 5), max(bd_data$date)),
                                            sep = ""),
                                pickerInput(inputId = "wilderness_2",
                                            label = "Select a wilderness",
                                            choices = unique(bd_data$wilderness),
                                            multiple = F,
                                            selected = ""),
                                pickerInput(inputId = "bd_species",
                                            label = "Select a species",
                                            choices = unique(bd_data$species),
                                            multiple = F,
                                            selected = "ramu"),
                                pickerInput(inputId = "stage",
                                            label = "Select a life stage",
                                            choices = unique(bd_data$visual_life_stage),
                                            selected = "adult",
                                            multiple = F),
                                pickerInput(inputId = "bd_id",
                                            label = "select site",
                                            choices = unique(bd_data$id),
                                            multiple = F)),
                        
                        mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "bd_plots")))
                      
             )
             

Server
server <- function(input, output, session){
 bd_reac <- reactive({
      
      bd_data %>% 
        dplyr::filter(date %in% input$bd_date[1:2], wilderness == input$wilderness_2, species == input$bd_species, 
                      visual_life_stage == input$stage, id == input$bd_id)
      
    })
    
    ### I believe my error is occuring with the filtering or plotting of the data here or just above
    output$bd_plots <- renderPlot({
      
      ggplot(data = bd_reac()) +
        geom_point(aes(x = date, y = bd)) +
        xlim(c(input$bd_date[1:2]))
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$bd_date, {
      
      updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "wilderness_2", 
                        choices = unique(bd_data$wilderness[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2]]), 
                        selected = "yosemite")
    })
    
    
    observeEvent(input$wilderness_2, {
      
      updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "bd_species", 
                        choices = unique(bd_data$species[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2] 
                                                          & bd_data$wilderness == input$wilderness_2]))
      
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$bd_species, {
      
      updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "stage", 
                        choices = unique(bd_data$visual_life_stage[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2] 
                                                     & bd_data$wilderness == input$wilderness_2 
                                                     & bd_data$species == input$bd_species]))
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$stage, {
      
      updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "bd_id",
                        choices = unique(bd_data$id[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2] 
                                                    & bd_data$wilderness == input$wilderness_2 
                                                    & bd_data$species == input$bd_species
                                                    & bd_data$visual_life_stage == input$stage]))
    })
    
    
    
}


Global

if (!require(librarian)){
  install.packages("librarian")
  library(librarian)
}

# librarian downloads, if not already downloaded, and reads in needed packages

librarian::shelf(shiny, tidyverse, here, shinyWidgets, leafem, bslib, thematic, shinymanager, leaflet, ggrepel, sf)
```

Comment: PLease simplify the code to highlight only the part that causes trouble if possible

Comment: There's parenthesis problem in the code

Comment: The data provided produces an error

Comment: Contact me on Telegram : `@julauto` to discuss more easily about this problem

Comment: I think the problem seems to be in `date %in% input$bd_date[1:2]`, A simple check returns FALSE. Try checking `date > input$date[1] & date < input$date[2]`. I didn't copy and download your code given it's not an MRE, so I may be off the mark in my suggestion.

Comment: Yes, try to replace `input$bd_date[1:2]` by `input$bd_date`

Comment: Since here, one has to give the whole vector of date, and not only the min and max

Comment: @Julien I have updated the data. Sorry for my mistake in creating a MRE.

Comment: @guasi no luck with your method

Comment: @Julien date == input$bd_date did not work and so did date %in% input$bd_date. Both still just return one date on the plot

Comment: For instance, I know this string of code will produce the correct df based on filtering choices. I am struggling to get this formate into shiny ```t <- bd_data %>% 
  filter(date %in% c(2016:2021), wilderness == "yosemite", species == "ramu", visual_life_stage == "adult", id == "70449")```

Comment: The data is still not correct

Comment: Did you replace `input$bd_date[1:2]` by `input$bd_date` in all the code ?

Comment: I'm going to bed

Comment: @Julien ok updated with a basic data structure.

Comment: Make the small change `bd_data - structure(list(id = c(10008, 10008,10008), date = c(2018,2019,2020), species = c("ramu", "ramu", "ramu"),
                                     wilderness = c("yosemite", "yosemite", "yosemite"), visual_life_stage = c("adult", "adult", "adult"),
                                     bd = c(1,2,3))) %>% as.data.frame()`

Answer (score 1):

Once you create a dataframe and use the dates as noted by @guasi, your code works fine.  Try this

```
bd_data <- data.frame(id = c(10008, 10008,10008), date = c(2018,2019,2020), 
                      species = c("ramu", "ramu", "ramu"),
                      wilderness = c("yosemite", "yosemite", "yosemite"), 
                      visual_life_stage = c("adult", "adult", "adult"),
                      bd = c(1,2,3) )



ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(column(8,
                    h1(strong("National Park Service App - RIBBiTR ")))),
    
    navbarPage("", inverse = T,
               
               tabPanel("Home", icon = icon("info-circle"),
                        fluidPage(
                          fluidRow(
                            h1(strong("Disclaimer"), style = "font-size:20px;"),
                            
                            column(12, p(""))),
                          
                          fluidRow(
                            h1(strong("Intended Use"),style = "font-size:20px;"),
                            
                            column(12, p(""))),
                          
                          fluidRow(
                            h1(strong("Data Collection"),style = "font-size:20px;"),
                            column(12, p(""))))),
               
               
               tabPanel(title = "Site Map", icon = icon("globe-asia"),
                        
                        sidebarLayout(
                          
                          sidebarPanel(
                            
                            sliderInput(inputId = "bd_date",
                                        label = "Select an annual range",
                                        min = min(bd_data$date), max = max(bd_data$date), 
                                        value =  c((max(bd_data$date) - 5), max(bd_data$date)),
                                        sep = ""),
                            pickerInput(inputId = "wilderness_2",
                                        label = "Select a wilderness",
                                        choices = unique(bd_data$wilderness),
                                        multiple = F,
                                        selected = ""),
                            pickerInput(inputId = "bd_species",
                                        label = "Select a species",
                                        choices = unique(bd_data$species),
                                        multiple = F,
                                        selected = "ramu"),
                            pickerInput(inputId = "stage",
                                        label = "Select a life stage",
                                        choices = unique(bd_data$visual_life_stage),
                                        selected = "adult",
                                        multiple = F),
                            pickerInput(inputId = "bd_id",
                                        label = "select site",
                                        choices = unique(bd_data$id),
                                        multiple = F)
                          ),
                          mainPanel(plotOutput(outputId = "bd_plots"))
                          )
               )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  bd_reac <- reactive({
    req(input$bd_date,input$wilderness_2,input$bd_species,input$stage,input$bd_id)
    bd_data %>% 
      dplyr::filter((date <= input$bd_date[2] & date >= input$bd_date[1]), 
                    wilderness == input$wilderness_2, species == input$bd_species, 
                    visual_life_stage == input$stage, id == input$bd_id)
    
  })
  
  ### I believe my error is occuring with the filtering or plotting of the data here or just above
  output$bd_plots <- renderPlot({
    req(bd_reac())
    ggplot(data = bd_reac(), aes(x = date, y = bd)) + 
      geom_point() + geom_line() +
      xlim(c(input$bd_date[1:2]))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$bd_date, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "wilderness_2", 
                      choices = unique(bd_data$wilderness[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2]]), 
                      selected = "yosemite")
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$wilderness_2, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "bd_species", 
                      choices = unique(bd_data$species[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2] 
                                                       & bd_data$wilderness == input$wilderness_2]))
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$bd_species, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "stage", 
                      choices = unique(bd_data$visual_life_stage[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2] 
                                                                 & bd_data$wilderness == input$wilderness_2 
                                                                 & bd_data$species == input$bd_species]))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$stage, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, inputId = "bd_id",
                      choices = unique(bd_data$id[bd_data$date %in% input$bd_date[1:2] 
                                                  & bd_data$wilderness == input$wilderness_2 
                                                  & bd_data$species == input$bd_species
                                                  & bd_data$visual_life_stage == input$stage]))
  })
  
}              

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I got a warning `Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "list"`

Comment: Once you create a data frame as shown above, it works fine for me.

Comment: Please accept the answer, if this has answered your query.